# Foreign key does not exist when deleting dependent records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reference, migration

I have two models. The first one:

```
class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :words, dependent: :delete_all

end
```

The second:

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

My migrations:

```
class Keywords < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :keywords do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false, unique: true
      t.string :description, null: false 
      t.string :keys, null: false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

And for the words:

```
class Words < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :words do |t|
      t.belongs_to :keyword
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

When I'm trying to delete the keywords instance Rails throws out the following exception:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column words.keyword_id does not exist LINE 1: DELETE FROM "words" WHERE "words"."keyword_id" = $1 ^ : DELETE FROM "words" WHERE "words"."keyword_id" = $1
```

So my question is, why Rails created `keyword_id` reference to the table instead of using `keywords_id`? And how to fix it.

Comment: It should create `keyword_id` column. How do you try to delete record?

Comment: Via the link in my view:

<%= link_to "delete", set, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>

Comment: Can you show the controller action then? Also, what is `set` - is it an instance of `Keyword`?

Comment: `def destroy
    Keyword.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Keyword set deleted"
    redirect_to keywords_path
  end`

Yes, `set` is an instance of the Keyword model.

Comment: Seems ok. What do you get when you run in the console: `Word.new.attributes.keys`?

Comment: `["id", "keywords_id", "name", "created_at", "updated_at"] `

Comment: Hmmmm, that's weird. Are you sure there are no other migrations modifying that column? Also, have you modified migration after it has run?

Comment: Yes, I've modified the migration files. But then droped and recreated the database from them. As you can see, there is a 'keywords_id' column, but when I'm trying to destroy a Keyword instance it references to 'keyword_id' column. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: You could use `foreign_key` option on the association, the real riddle is why it created such a weird column. Are you 100% sure you don't modify this column in another migration? Try dropping the whole database again, run `spring stop` and then rerun migrations.

Comment: Tried to recreate the database, spring was not running. Still the same error.

Comment: Any chance you have code on github? There must be something missing here.

Comment: https://github.com/ksukhorukov/Googler

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you'll need to add a `belongs_to` relation to your `Word` model:

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :keyword
end
```

Secondly, to create the column `keyword_id` for the foreign key, you'll need to use the `add_reference` method in your migration:

```
class Words < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :words do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_reference :words, :keyword, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

If what you actually want is to have a many-to-many relation, you'll need to add a join table, i.e. `KeywordsWords`.

Comment: `belongs_to` is an alias for `reference` method. Migration code is correct.

Comment: @BroiSatse: Thanks for pointing that out. Corrected my answer.

Comment: Yes, sure. `rake db:drop && rake db:setup`

Answer (score 0):

The code in your repository is actually different than migration code you posted. In your repo you have:

```
t.belongs_to :keywords
```

Change it to:

```
t.belongs_to :keyword
```

as you posted in the question and then recreate the database.

Comment: Ok, how do you recreate the database?

Comment: `rake db:drop && rake db:setup`

Comment: And everything is clear - `rake db:setup` does not run migrations but loads the content of `schema.rb` file. This file is generated every time you run your migrations. Since your migrations were incorrect the last time you run them, your schema contains invalid column name and you keep loading it back to your database. Do `rake db:drop`, `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate` instead.

Comment: Now I have the following error during the last step:

`rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant CreateKeywords`

Comment: I've changed the classname of the first migration to 'CreateKeywords', now I have another error:

``ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "words" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"words"'::regclass
                                          ^
``

Comment: That means that class defined within migration file does not match the name of the migration file. If the file is named `<timestamp>_create_keywords`, it has to define `CreateKeywords` migration class.

Comment: Eh we really need to chat about that, as there are just way too much issues with your migrations now. Which migration throws this error?

Comment: Finally solved! I renamed all my migration files, basically added 'create_' prefix to the tablenames. Also tablenames are in singular form there like:
``20151009131748_create_keyword.rb``
And changed the class names of all migrations, e.g.: ``CreateKeyword``
After that all migrations completed smoothly and now I'm able to delete the keywords sets.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need the following:

```
#app/models/keyword.rb
class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :words
end

#app/models/word.rb
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :keyword
end
```

This will lead Rails to look for the `keyword_id` foreign key in the `words` table:

```
#words
id | keyword_id | name | created_at | updated_at
```

Looks like you need to change your `words` table to include the `keyword_id` foreign key:

```
$ rails g migration ChangeWordsAddKeywordID

#db/migrate/change_words_add_keyword_id______.rb
class ChangeWordsAddKeywordID
   def change
     rename_column :words, :keywords_ids, :keyword_id
     ## OR ##
     create_column :words, :keyword_id, :integer
   end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```